# SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON default setting is saved where

Tags: settings, sql-server-2000

I need to find out the default quoted_identifier setting for a SQL Server 2000 database. `@@options` exist for SQL Server 2008 R2 (and on) but I need to figure out what the setting is for a SQL Server 2000 database via T-SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an instanse of SQL Server 2000, so can't test the result.
The only solution I found was to check with

```
OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id,'ExecIsQuotedIdentOn')
```

For example:

```
SELECT  
    SCHEMA_NAME(s.schema_id)  + '.' + s.name AS name,
    s.create_date, 
    s.modify_date, 
    OBJECTPROPERTY(s.object_id,'ExecIsQuotedIdentOn') AS IsQuotedIdentOn
FROM sys.objects s  
WHERE  
    s.type IN ('P','TR','V','IF','FN','TF')
    AND OBJECTPROPERTY(s.object_id,'ExecIsQuotedIdentOn') = 0
ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME(s.schema_id)  + '.' + s.name DESC
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I gave credit to Andrey but for anyone who needs to run this on 2000 where (sysobject exists not sys.objects etc.) this is the code that works:

```
SELECT  
     s.name AS name,
     OBJECTPROPERTY(s.id,'ExecIsQuotedIdentOn') AS IsQuotedIdentOn
FROM sysobjects s  
WHERE  
    s.type IN ('P','D', 'K','S','U','V')
    AND OBJECTPROPERTY(s.id,'ExecIsQuotedIdentOn') = 1
ORDER BY  s.name DESC
```